# Laravel model query with sum and grouping

Tags: laravel

I have a table like this:

```
|item_name  |uom    |qty    |order_number

|bike       |pc     |1      |101
|ball       |pc     |2      |102
|bike       |pc     |5      |103
|car        |pc     |3      |106
|bike       |pc     |4      |108
|ball       |pc     |1      |109
|bike       |pc     |6      |115
|car        |pc     |1      |111
```

And I want to see in a view this data:

```
bike - 16 pcs overall:
101 - 1
103 - 5
108 - 4
115 - 6

ball - 3 pcs overall:
102 - 2
109 - 1
```

etc...
I tried wuth this query, but I think it is not correct, because it gives me only name and sum of qty:

```
$saps = Item::where('year', 2019)->groupBy('item_name')->selectRaw('item_name, sum(qty) as sum')->get('item_name','sum');
```

Comment: Because you are selecting only `item_name` and `sum`, that why you are getting only those two values.

Comment: This is how the SQL `group by` works so in that sense it's correct. Maybe you need to use the [collection group by](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-groupby) method instead to get something closer to what you want

Answer (score 1):

```
Item::where('year', 2019)
    ->select('name','order_number',\DB::raw("SUM(qty) as qty"))
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1')
    ->get();
```

Try this query.

Outupt

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
$saps = Item::where('year', 2019)->selectRaw('order_number, qty')
                    ->groupBy('item_name')
                    ->get();
```

Or

```
$saps = Item::where('year', 2019)->selectRaw('order_number, qty,item_name')
                    ->get();

$saps_new = $saps->groupBy('item_name')->map(function ($row) {
                    return $row->sum('qty');
            });
```

Comment: It will not work. it returns sum of qty with first order number of item name

Comment: @YasinPatel I guess it will work now, but it wont get exact result as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the initial groups with this:

```
$saps = Item::where('year', 2019)->selectRaw("SUM(qty) as total, item_name, id")
                ->groupBy('item_name')
                ->get();
```

You can then lazy or eager load the listing for each item.

If you go with lazy loading you can map on results and then lazy load the listing based on each item

```
$saps->map(function($item){
     $items = Item::where('year', 2019)->where('item_name', $item->item_name)
                ->get();
}
```

or eager load like this:

```
Item::where('year', 2019)->whereIn('item_name', $saps)
            ->get();
```